# Sending notification not working on Oreo

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to send a notification but it doesn't get shown, also no exception is being thrown. I have tested this on Android 8.0. I have heard that you need to use a NotificationChannel or something like that but I have tried using that and it still doesn't work or I must have used it wrong.

```
private void sendNotifications() {
    final Random random = new Random();
    try {
        for (QuoteData data : quoteData) {
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                    notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            Quote quote = data.getQuotes().get(random.nextInt(data.getQuotes().size()));
            String quoteMessage;
            if (quote.getSayer().isEmpty()) {
                quoteMessage = quote.getMessage();
            } else {
                quoteMessage = quote.getMessage() + "-" + quote.getSayer();
            }

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            Notification n = new Notification.Builder(context)
                    .setContentTitle(data.getTitle())
                    .setContentText(quoteMessage)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_black_24dp)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true).build();

            notificationManager.notify(AlarmReceiver.getId(), n);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: In Android 8.0(Oreo) [Notification Channel](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) got introduced which u need to implement in your app.

Comment: Yeah I heard of that but I don't know how to implement it in this code.

Comment: Check this [link](https://medium.com/exploring-android/exploring-android-o-notification-channels-94cd274f604c). Hope it will help you.

Comment: Hey, I checked out the link and went to the creating a notification and it the .setChannelId requires API level 26

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android O it's a must to use a channel with your Notification Builder

Try with this code

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); 
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) { 
NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "My Notifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
// Configure the notification channel.
notificationChannel.setDescription("Channel description");

notificationChannel.enableLights(true);   
notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED); 

notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000});
notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);     

 notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
} 

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID) .setVibrate(new long[]{0, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100}) 
    .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)) 
    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher) .setContentTitle("Content Title") 
    .setContentText("Content Text"); 
notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your channel like this

```
 public void initChannels(Context context) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 26) {
        return;
    }
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("default",
            "YOUR_CHANNEL_NAME",
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
    channel.setDescription("Channel description");
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
}
```

Pass to your notification builder like this

```
notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,"default")
```

Comment: The second argument in the constructor requires API level 26

Comment: Notification Channel issue occurs only in 26+ API other wise its working fine in my all app in oreo

Answer (score 0):

```
String CHANNEL_NAME="some_name"
String CHANNEL_ID="some_id"

private void sendNotifications() {
    final Random random = new Random();
    try {
        for (QuoteData data : quoteData) {
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            Quote quote = data.getQuotes().get(random.nextInt(data.getQuotes().size()));
            String quoteMessage;
            if (quote.getSayer().isEmpty()) {
                quoteMessage = quote.getMessage();
            } else {
                quoteMessage = quote.getMessage() + "-" + quote.getSayer();
            }

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            // Using AppCompat library
            NotificationCompat.Builder n = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context,CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setContentTitle(data.getTitle())
                    .setContentText(quoteMessage)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_black_24dp)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true).build();

            // To support Android O devices
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(new NotificationChannelGroup(CHANNEL_ID, 
                            CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT))
            }

            notificationManager.notify(AlarmReceiver.getId(), n);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```